# Is it possible to set Notes with automatically inserted values using google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was trying to figure out a way to insert Notes automatically, when i enter something in a specific cell. This thread was suggested to me and tried it out: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/13317657?hl=en. I changed the function mentioned a littlebit, to fit my project:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === 'Testsheet') { 
    if(e.range.columnStart === 8 && (e.range.rowStart > 12 && e.range.rowStart < 21)) {
        return e.range.offset(0, -6).setNote(e.value);  
      }
    }
  }
```

This way when I enter values in the range H13:H20, the same values get inserted as Notes on the corresponding (0, -6) offset cells. Which is a step in the right direction, but not yet what I'm truly trying to achieve. The problem is, this only works, when the values are entered manually. But for my project, I need the notes also to be set, when values are filled in automatically, using a function that fills in certain information in a row, depending on the selected dropdown choice.

In my sheet for example:

`=if(B17="Test1",Testsheet!C10:Testsheet!H10)`
When the Information is filled in that way, it doesn't give me the Note in the offset cell. Is there a way, so that it does?

Here is a link to my Testsheet, where you can see what I'm trying to do : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16c2hVDM_FTnHWerKjnOauCopwVZSnKCwAMVi6-Z8vBo/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for any tips and help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions):

> Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For
>   example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the
>   spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.

The only option would be to directly run the notes function with the values as parameter instead of inserting the "row 16" values, as updating the sheet by a script or formula won't trigger the function `onEdit()`.

Comment: this might be a stupid question, but would it instead be possible, to write a different script (like a button) and if pressed, it puts the all the information from a certain cell(or range) into the note? If something like this is possible, this would be a acceptable workaround for me.

Comment: Yes, you can create a button and run a function when is pressed.  [Get the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) from the cells and use them in your `setNote` replacing `e.value`.