# Button for Setting Notes using Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a button script for google sheets, that takes values from a certain range, and creates Notes in the corresponding (0,-6) offset cells.

**For example:** *"G1" has the text "Text1", "G2" hast the text "Text2" and so on up to "G10" with text "Text10". Now If I run the script, I want "A1" to have a note saying "Text1", "A2" with the note "Text2" and so on.*

For anyone of you wondering, I can't use an onEdit function, since in my case the Values from e.g. *G1:G10*, will change automatically, not by user editing, as explained to me in this thread: [Is it possible to set Notes with automatically inserted values using google sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58692892/is-it-possible-to-set-notes-with-automatically-inserted-values-using-google-shee)

I am a beginner, so I'm not sure how to write a script like this from scratch. Any pushes in the right direction would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
function makeNotes() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,7,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  vA.forEach(function(r,i){
    sh.getRange(i+1,1).setNote(r[0]);
  })
}
```

[Instructions for Creating a Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58532556/7215091)

Comment: thanks! works like a charm. Just to understand get.range better. What section would I change, if I want the notes to appear in the B column, instead of A?

Comment: [Read this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) and work through the example.  It's all in the documentation.